# Linear dependence between id random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $f,g$ be iid random variables and let $h$ be linearly dependent on $f,g$.

If all three variables have the same distribution, can we conclude that they are all normal?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot conclude that $f, g$ and $h$ are normal.  For example, if $f$ and $g$ are i.i.d. Cauchy random variables with density $[\pi(1+x^2)]^{-1}$, then $h = (f+g)/2$ is also a Cauchy random variable with the same density.